# Scroll jQuery dataTable to desired row

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll

I have a jQuery dataTable

```
var oTable = $('#table1').dataTable({
      'aaData': data,
      'aoColumns': cols,
      'bScrollInfinite': true,
      'bScrollCollapse': true,
      'sScrollY': '200px'
});
```

I want to scroll to the last row of the table. It currently has 500 rows.

```
$('#table1').scrollTo($('#table tbody tr').last(), 800);
```

The above code does not work.

Hoever, when i target `body` tag

```
$('body').scrollTo('900px', 800);
```

It works fine.

I am using the plugin http://demos.flesler.com/jquery/scrollTo/

Answer (score 0):

I believe it needs the pixel value as parameter, try this code below:

```
$('#table1').scrollTo($('#table tbody tr').last().offset().top, 800);
```

Comment: Well, I think you need to put your HTML into your question. Or you can create a Fiddle.. Anyway, are you sure it's `#table` instead of `#table1` ?